# How to constraint a type variable with multiple constraints?

Tags: scala

I have the following types:

```
object Messenger {

  sealed trait MessageOrigin

  case object SAP extends MessageOrigin

  case object KAFKA extends MessageOrigin

  final case class Message(topic: String, event: String,
                           data: String, origin: MessageOrigin,
                           proceed: Long = java.time.Instant.now().toEpochMilli) 

  sealed trait MessageCmd

  case class SaveMessage(value: Message) extends MessageCmd

  sealed trait MessageEvent

  case class MessageSaved(value: Message) extends MessageEvent

  final case class MessageState(value: Message = Message("", "", "", SAP))

}



object Logger {

  sealed trait Level

  final case object Error extends Level

  final case object Warning extends Level

  final case object Info extends Level

  final case class Log(level: Level, msg: String)

  sealed trait LogCmd

  final case class SaveLog(value: Log) extends LogCmd

  sealed trait LogEvent

  final case class LogSaved(value: Log) extends LogEvent

  final case class LogState(value: Log = Log(Info, "Initial"))


}
```

What I would like to do is, to constraint the following type variable `A` of the following case class to:

```
 final case class TrashTalk[A : LogCmd, MessageCmd](value: A)
```

but the compiler complains:

```
scala> final case class TrashTalk[A : LogCmd, MessageCmd](value: A)
<console>:19: error: LogCmd does not take type parameters
       final case class TrashTalk[A : LogCmd, MessageCmd](value: A)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to constrain your type to? `SaveMessage`? Something that extends `MessageCmd`?

Comment: The type `A` should be either `LogCmd` or `MessageCmd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `LogCmd` and `MessageCmd` are not type classes so the `:` syntax won't work even if you only specify a single type.

```
final case class TrashTalk[A : LogCmd](value: A) // Error
```

It should be

```
final case class TrashTalk[A <: LogCmd](value: A)// OK
```

Secondly, Scala does not support union types so even this won't work

```
final case class TrashTalk[A <: LogCmd, MessageCmd](value: A) // Error
```

You need to create a typeclass `Cmd` that wraps both `LogCmd` and `MessageCmd` and use that:

```
trait Cmd[-T]

object Cmd {
  implicit object logCmd extends Cmd[Logger.LogCmd]
  implicit object msgCmd extends Cmd[Messenger.MessageCmd]
}

final case class TrashTalk[A : Cmd](value: A)
```